# Fancybox Error and not working on server

Tags: internet-explorer, fancybox, syntax-error

I set up fancybox on this website. It works fine when I test it locally, however, when I upload it to the server it does not work. I've tried it in Chrome, Firefox, and IE. IE tells me there is an error in line 29 char 4. I have copied the code exactly from Fancybox sample code.

I have also tried changing the script paths since I have the site setup in a sub directory to test. Still no luck. This is one of those situations where I have looked at this too many times and just seem to be missing something. Anyone care to lend an eye?

Much thanks.

http://www.insightdezign.net/esd/weddings.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
```

does not seem to link to a fancybox.js